# Progress 4GL query with optional "break by"

Tags: break, progress-4gl

I have a query:

```
for each a where ...,
    each b where ...,
    each c where ...,
      break by c.xxx by c.yyy by c.zzz.
```

I need the break by's to vary according to user input.

When I try to define a query:

```
def query qa for a, b, c. 
if ... then open qa for each a... (as above)
```

then it won't compile because:

```
BREAK requires query be defined SCROLLING. (14283)
```

How can I set variables for the "break by"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "query-prepare".  That's the magic that lets you completely customize your query.

I happened to be writing such a query this morning:

```
/* dyn.p
 */

define variable tbl as character no-undo.
define variable brk as character no-undo.

define variable b   as handle no-undo.
define variable q   as handle no-undo.

tbl = "customer".
brk = "state".

create query  q.
create buffer b for table tbl.

q:set-buffers( b ).

q:query-prepare( "for each " + tbl + " break by " + brk ).
q:query-open.
q:get-next().

do while q:query-off-end = false:

  if q:first-of( 1 ) then clear all.

  display
    b:buffer-field( 'CustNum' ):buffer-value()
    b:buffer-field( 'Name'    ):buffer-value()
    b:buffer-field( 'State'   ):buffer-value()
   with
    down
  .

  down 1.

  q:get-next().


end.

return.
```

Run the code above against "sports2000".